# start Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

i am writing a windows service that checks for a particular service and check it. if it is stop it will start it...

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServiceThreadFunction));
        thread.Start();
    }

public void ServiceThreadFunction()
    {

        try
        {
            ServiceController dc = new ServiceController("WebClient");

            //ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

            while (true)
            {

                if ((int)dc.Status == 1)
                {                  


                    dc.Start();
                    WriteLog(dc.Status.ToString);
                    if ((int)dc.Status == 0)
                    {

                        //heartbeat
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    //service started
                }
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        // log errors
        }
    }
```

i want the service to check for the another service and start... plz help me how can i do that

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you are using? Where is it going wrong?

Comment: And why are you casting enums to ints instead of comparing with the appropriate enum values directly? That would make this more readable.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, why are you casting the ServiceController's Status property from the convenient ServiceControllerStatus enum to an int? Best to leave it as an enum. Especially since your Heartbeat code, which compares it to 0, will never be run because ServiceControllerStatus doesn't have 0 as a possible value.

Secondly, you shouldn't use a while(true) loop. Even with the Thread.Sleep you have commented out there, it's a needless drain on resources. You can just use the WaitForStatus method to wait for the service to start:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("WebClient");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    sc.Start();
    sc.WaitForStatus (ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```

This will wait up to 30 seconds (or whatever) for the service to reach the Running state.

**UPDATE**: I re-read the original question, and I think what you're trying to do here shouldn't even be done with code. If I understood correctly, you want to set a dependency for your service on the WebClient service when you're installing it. Then, when the user starts your service in the Service Manager, it will automatically try to start the dependent service.